# Proof Question - Calculus

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

**Proof Question - Calculus**

Proof that if $a>1/4$ so to the equation $\sin x = \sqrt{x}+\frac{a}{\sqrt{x}}$ there is no real solutions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Clearly $x > 0$.
By AMGM
$$\sqrt{x} + \frac{a}{\sqrt{x}} \geq 2\sqrt{a} > 2*1/2 =1$$

Since $0 \leq |\sin(x)| \leq 1$ , there are no solutions.

Comment: if i`m isolate x its mean that x= arcsin(...) right? and arcsin is [-1,1] -> [-pi/2,pi/2] so your answer still get it?

Comment: x cannot be negative as RHS will not make sense.